# Reference @ConstructorBinding's in SpEL not works?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-el

I have a final config-class like this:

```java
@Value // <- lombok-annotation
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties("my-app.conf")
public class MyProperties {
  Duration reloadPeriod;
}
```

And I want to use the `reloadPeriod` in a `@Scheduled` field like this:

```java
@Service
public class MyService {

   @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "#{myProperties.reloadPeriod}")
   public void doSomeRecurrentStuff() {
      // some work
   }
}
```

But this setup will always fail with this error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'myProperties' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?

When I add an "intermediate bean" like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfigClass {

   @Bean("reloadPeriod")
   Duration reloadPeriod(MyProperties props) {
      return props.getReloadPeriod();
   }
}
```

then I can reference it without any problems like this: `@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "#{reloadPeriod}")`

## tldr;

How can I access "like beans" created by `@ConstructorBinding`  via SpEL?

Comment: have you checked [How to reference a bean by type in a SpEL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59771574/how-to-reference-a-bean-by-type-in-a-spel)

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov no, I doesn't saw this one. But it is the same question, so mine is duplicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `beanFactory` to get the configuration properties bean by its type.

```java
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = 
            "#{beanFactory.getBean(T(com.package.MyProperties)).reloadPeriod}")
public void doSomeRecurrentStuff() {
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, implement [`SchedulingConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/SchedulingConfigurer.html) to programmatically set up scheduled tasks.

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfigurer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.config.ScheduledTaskRegistrar;

@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private MyProperties myProperties;
    
    void doSomeRecurrentStuff() {
        // some work
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.addFixedDelayTask(this::doSomeRecurrentStuff, 
              myProperties.getReloadPeriod());
    }
}
```

Comment: That works, but my package-name is quite long. Did you know a way without the full-name?

Comment: @akop I've updated my answer to show a method using `SchedulingConfigurer`.